# python method() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, django

I have a class like this in django app views.py

```
from dms.models import Folder, File, FileTag

class GetFamily:

    def getFathers(folder_id):
        if folder_id == None:
            rev_fathers=None
        else:
            fathers=[]
            rev_fathers=[]
            father=Folder.objects.get(id=folder_id)
            fathers.append(father)
            while father.parent_folder_id != None:
                father=Folder.objects.get(id=father.parent_folder_id)
                fathers.append(father)
            rev_fathers=reversed(fathers)
        return rev_fathers

    def getChildrenFolders(folder_id):
        folders=Folder.objects.filter(parent_folder_id=folder_id)
        return folders  

    def getChildrenFiles(folder_id):
        files=File.objects.filter(folder_id=folder_id)
        return files
```

When i call getFathers(folder_id) method with id it gives
  getFathers() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Plese help me out

Comment: Why is this a class at all, rather than simply a collection of functions? What does grouping them under `GetFamily` give you? Remember Python is not Java.

Comment: Yes you are right   :-p
I can make three functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`getFathers` is a method of class `GetFamily`, so it needs a first parameter for the instance. The convention in python is to use the name `self` for this parameter:

```
def getFathers(self, folder_id):
```

Note that the function itself does not access any of the class' members. This is often a good indicator that it does not need to be a method of the class, or that it would be declared as a static method using `@staticmethod`.

Answer (score 1):

Either include `self` in the arguments:

```
def getFathers(self, folder_id):
```

Or, if it won't need any instance variables, mark it as a `staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def getFathers(folder_id):
```